# arroba e aspas seguidas em uma string (saindo &quot; ou #39; na View)

Tags: c#, html, .net, string, concatenação-de-string

Estou tentando colocar o seguinte texto em uma string, mas não consigo... quando não da erro nas aspas duplas da no arroba... to ficando doido. Alguém pode me ajudar?

> ,{
>       "@type": "ListItem",
>       "position": 2,
>       "item": {
>       "@id": "http://www.enderecosite.com",
>       "name": "descrição xyz",
>       "image": "http://enderecosite/tumb-compartilhamento-facebook.jpg"
>       }
>       }

Estou tentando algo tipo:

```
string TextoComplicado = ",{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": 2,
"item": {
"@id": "http://www.enderecosite.com",
"name": "descrição xyz",
"image": "http://enderecosite/tumb-compartilhamento-facebook.jpg"
}
}";
```

Essa variavél será colocada dentro de uma tag script na minha View:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> @*Apenas detalhes do Imovél?*@
   @Model.TextoComplicado 
</script>
```

Se coloco ' (aspas simples) é printado #39; no lugar das aspas

Se coloco \" é printado ecomercial quot; no lugar das aspas

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aspas simples é pra char, por isso o #39 (Código ASCII).

E aspas duplas é para iniciar ou finalizar uma string. Se você precisa colocar uma no meio da string, utilize um caractere de escape: `\`:

Exemplo:

```
string x = """; //Erro

string y = "\""; //OK
```

Seu caso, ficaria algo assim:

```
string teste = " \"@type\": \"ListItem\"";
```

Edit:

Tente usar o `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string);` para que o valor da string não seja exibido como código Html.

Exemplo:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> @*Apenas detalhes do Imovél?*@
   @System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.TextoComplicado) 
</script>
```

Comment: Valew Rovan, mas a saída na minha página está sendo &quot no lugar das aspas

Comment: vi isso... um momento que vou acertar... aí já é uma questão do html...

Comment: Tem toda razão (é coisa do html). Na view usei o @Html.Raw(Model.TextoComplicado)  e bum! Funcionou!!! Valew!

Comment: HtmlDecode tbm Ok! Valew mesmo

Comment: Se resolveu, não esqueça de marcar como resposta. Vlw

Answer (score 1):

Faça dessa forma :

```
        string TextoComplicado =
            ",{\r\n\"@type\": \"ListItem\",\r\n\"position\": 2,\r\n\"item\": {\r\n\"@id\": \"http://www.enderecosite.com\",\r\n\"name\": \"descrição xyz\",\r\n\"image\": \"http://enderecosite/tumb-compartilhamento-facebook.jpg\"\r\n}\r\n}";
```

Exemplo aqui:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/1a05FX

Comment: Obrigado @Thiago. Tentei aqui, mas está printando &quot; no lugar das aspas duplas

Comment: tente utilizar também o HtmlDecode, veja se resolve.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332854%28v=vs.71%29.aspx